# Using a Polymer Behavior function in a template

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm new to polymer and this may be an obvious question. I'm running into an issue where I can't getting an not defined function error when one of my elements is loading.

Here is a code snippet:

```
   <link rel='import' href='../polymer/polymer.html'>
   <link rel='import' href='../app-localize-behavior/app-localize-behavior.html'>
   <link rel='import' href='../paper-button/paper-button.html'>
   <dom-module id='client'>
       <template>
          <div class='buttonContainer'>
             <paper-button raised id='closeChat' class="green">{{localize('agent.closeChat')}}</paper-button>  
          </div>
       </template>
       <script>
       Client = Polymer({
       is: "client-interface",
       behaviors: [
        Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior
       ],

       // works as expected
       attached: function() {
         this.loadResources(this.resolveUrl('./locales.json'))
       },
    </script>

 </dom-module>
```

The 'localize' function is throwing an error and stops the template from loading. If I call the localize function after the 'attached' callback is fired, the localize method is available.

What is the idiomatic way to avoid these loading issues if I'm calling a function from a behavior inside my template?

Comment: First of all: custom element should contain dash in its definition (as described in [guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements)).
The example provided by you should work well. What kind of error is thrown?

Comment: @VladMinaev I've updated the definition as you mentioned but I'm still receiving 'localizer undefined' errors from the template

Comment: ok can you provide the full listing of your element